# Kintone calendar event range display color

Tags: javascript

I am trying to customize kintone app. So far, I have only been able to use kintone.app to get record fields by codename and set text color. But that is it. I need access to the table. I want to highlight all the days within a range of an event that would last for several days.
API seems to limit the level of customization.
Does anyone have any experience with kintone or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only suggestion would be to customize it using DOM manipulation, but please keep in mind that it might not work after the update.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

At this point, KINTONE does not allow displaying event ranges as colored bars stretching over days.
The only best way to achieve it is to use Google calendar or fullcalendar.io alternatives.
Simply inject the calendar in place of the one provided by KINTON. Easy but keep in mind that KINTONE may change things and render your super imposed invention useless by an update.